# Superpings don't show user name in sidebar

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, super-ping

Doorknob just superpinged someone [in our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19948010#19948010). The message got starred and ended up in the sidebar. However, the superping syntax and user ID weren't replaced with the normal ping and user name there (as they are in the actual message):

[image]
<sup>Click for larger version</sup>

I don't think it's a big deal, but a bit of an inconsistency (and makes the starred message a lot less informative).

**Edit:** [Doorknob has edited the message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19950286#19950286) since I posted this question. It no longer contains the superping, so you won't be able to reproduce this by visiting the chatroom now. The screenshot was taken before his edit.

Comment: Ah, so *that's* what a superping looks like!

Comment: If you want to see it reproduced, see https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/666/481